# Enviar post a fichero PHP fuera de carpeta publica

Tags: php, html, html5, post

estoy teniendo un problema, quisiera enviar un POST a un fichero PHP que se encuentra fuera de la carpeta pública, pero no consigo apuntar a dicho fichero. Espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Mi index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="cómo puedo enviar a procesa.php?" method ="post">
    <input type="text" name ="datos">
    <button type="submit">Click</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

procesa.php

```
   <?php
   echo $_POST["datos"];
```

Estructura de carpetas

[image: Estructura de mis carpetas]

Comment: Tendrías que poner toda la ruta; host/carpea/archivo.php

Comment: Me sale un error 403. Acceso prohibido. Usted no tiene acceso para acceder al objeto solicitado. Estoy usando xampp

Comment: Puedes poner el `action` de este modo: `action="../ficheros/procesa.php"`. Lo que indicas con `../` es que retroceda un directorio, poniéndose a nivel para poder entrar en `ficheros` y luego en `procesa.php`. El error 403 es debido seguramente a que el usuario no tiene al menos permiso de lectura, sea sobre el archivo en sí, sea sobre la carpeta `ficheros`, debes por tanto otorgarle permiso de lectura al menos.

Comment: Los usuarios no tienen acceso a lo que haya fuera de la carpeta pública (la raíz de tu servidor web). Entonces una cosa que podrías intentar es mandar el formulario a un archivo que esté dentro de la carpeta pública (y por tanto con acceso para el usuario) y en ese archivo incluyes el fichero “externo” procesa.php.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro Montoro. Así funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como te respondieron en los comentarios, vía Web no tienes acceso a los archivos que están fuera de la carpeta pública de tu servidor o DOCUMENTROOT, es una excelente configuración/práctica de seguridad para dejar protegidos los archivos que tienen toda la lógica de nuestra aplicación.

Para lo que necesitas puedes usar el siguiente ej. como guía:

El index.php se envía a si mismo como parámetro la acción que quiere realizar `(?do=accion1 en la acción del formulario o si quieres puedes usar un campo hidden y enviarlo por POST o cómo tú quieras)`. Éste index que está en la carpeta pública actúa como controlador frontal (*un único archivo PHP a través del cual se procesan todas las peticiones del usuario*) recibe los parámetros, los procesa y ejecuta las acciones que correspondan accediendo a los archivos que están en la parte "protegida" de nuestra app.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$do = $_GET['do'] ?? null;

if ($do) {
    switch ($do) {
        case 'accion1':
            // tu codigo para la accion 1
            require_once '../ficheros/procesa.php';

            break;
        case 'accion2':
            // tu codigo para la accion 1
            require_once '../ficheros/procesa.php';
            break;

        default:
            // hacer algo x default o simplemente ignorar
            break;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php?do=accion1" method ="post">
    <input type="text" name ="datos">
    <button type="submit">Click</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Genial, de hecho eso hice en último momento, entiendo que PHP puede tener acceso a todo el sistema, pero me parecía como que muy pesado para el servidor recibir la petición en un PHP en carpeta pública y luego enviarlo a otro para su proceso pero ahora comprendo que mi lógica iba por buen camino. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente!, como dato: Frameworks como Laravel, Symfony usan controlador frontal...un único lugar de acceso a la app = mejor control sobre las acciones que se pueden realizar..

Comment: Oh eso no sabía, muchas gracias por el dato. Saludos.